# Why does dirent.h not work on sshfs drives?

Tags: c++, sshfs, dirent.h

Here is the code I used to test it.
It works on ordinary directories, but not those mounted under sshfs.
My goal is to use these methods in
https://github.com/jlettvin/Greased-Grep
which is designed to allow global fuzzy searches for
keywords which must be present and keywords which must be absent.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <dirent.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::function;

bool neither (const char* path)
{
        bool ret = (path != nullptr);
        if (ret)
        {
                if (path[0] == '.')
                {
                        if (path[1] == '\0') ret = false;
                        if (path[1] == '.' && path[2] == '\0') ret = false;
                }
        }
        return ret;
}

void walk (const string &path, function<void (const string &)> talk)
{
    if (auto dir = opendir (path.c_str ())) {
        while (auto f = readdir (dir)) {
                        auto name = f->d_name;
                        auto type = f->d_type;
                        if (neither (name))
                        {
                                switch (type)
                                {
                                        case DT_DIR: walk (path + name + "/", talk); break;
                                        case DT_REG: talk (path + name            ); break;
                                }
                        }
        }
        closedir(dir);
    }
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
        walk ("./", [](const string &path) { cout << path << endl; });
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What "does not work" mean?

Comment: No files are reported from an sshfs directory but all files are reported from non-sshfs directories.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a dir. entry returned by readdir is a directory, link or file. dent->d\_type isn't showing the type](//stackoverflow.com/q/23958040) Or at least highly related.  Your super-simple answer could be optimized by only considering it as a possible directory for DT_DIR, DT_UNKNOWN, or symlinks.  So you'd avoid wasting time trying to opendir on names where you did get a positive ID from the kernel of `DT_REG` or a device or fifo.

Answer (score 4):

You need to [review the following documentation in the Linux's `readdir(3)` manual page](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman3/readdir.3.html):

> ```
>   unsigned char       d_type;     /* Type of file; not supported
>                                 by all filesystem types */
> ```

Specifically, your attention is directed to the "not supported by all filesystem types" part.

Your code expects `d_type` to be set. However, `readdir(3)` does not guarantee that it will be.

One of the possible values for `d_type` is:

> ```
> DT_UNKNOWN
>
>     The file type could not be determined.
> ```

Code that should be prepared to handle all possibilities must explicitly check for `DT_UNKNOWN`, and, if so, append `d_name` to the directory name, `stat()` the filename, and then grab the file type from there.

`d_type` is a shortcut. If it's set, wonderful. You have it right off the bat. If not, you'll have to work to get it.

`sshfs` obviously does not support returning `d_type` from `readdir(3)`. Hopefully, `sshfs` implements `stat()`.

P.S., not that besides a directory and regular files, there are also several other special types that you may or may not have to handle (assuming that `sshfs` can even provide them to you). That's something you will need to investigate on your own.

Comment: sshfs now supports returning `d_type` correctly again: https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/pull/591 Before, it always returned `d_type = DT_UNKNOWN`, requiring a `stat()` necessary, and many directory operations much slower. Of course user code should alway simplementing falling back to `stat()` et al when `DT_UNKNOWN` is encountered nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

I have the code I wanted operational.

After massive experimentation with all manner of sensitivity to all sorts of flags and conditions and situations I have decided to go with utter simplicity.

I treat EVERYTHING found as BOTH a directory and file.  If it is not a directory, I detect and ignore all errors and continue.  If it is a directory, then I open it and search its contents for what I want.  This is an advantage in Greased-Grep where the goal is to find things matching patterns.  Filenames are things, just like their contents.

So, my answer is, I do not care about failures.  I only care about successes, so I dismiss failures without any tests.

This works just fine when descending sshfs mounted directories.

Anyone interested in how this code looks can follow my github:
https://github.com/jlettvin/Greased-Grep/blob/master/gg.cpp

Here is the salient code:

```
void walk (const string& a_path)
{
    // Don't attempt to assess validity of filenames... just fail.
    // Treat directories like files and search filenames in directories.
    // This enables gg to work on sshfs mounted filesystems.
    auto d{a_path};
    auto s{d.size ()};
    if (s && d[s - 1] == '/') d.resize (s-1);
    errno = 0;
    if (auto dir = opendir (d.c_str ()))
    {
        while (!errno)
        {
            if (auto f = readdir (dir))
            {
                if (auto p = f->d_name)
                {
                    if (auto q = p)
                    {
                        if (!(*q++ == '.' && (!*q || (*q++ == '.' && !*q))))
                        {
                            auto e = d + "/" + p;
                            walk (e);
                            mapped_search (e.c_str ());
                            errno = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else break;
                }
                else break;
            }
            else break;
        }
    }
}
```